# Code iterating through whole string in hangman

Tags: vb.net

How can I stop my code from iterating through a whole string stating whether the input from the user matches that of the random string bearing in mind this is for a hangman game, I want the code to just display once if the user's chosen letter is either correct or incorrect rather than displaying up too eight times.

```
Sub letterInput()
    For i As Integer = 0 To randomWord.Length - 1
        If userInput = randomWord(i) Then
            MessageBox.Show("correct")

        ElseIf userInput <> randomWord(i) Then
            MessageBox.Show("incorrect")
            Label4.Text = counter
            Exit for


        End If
    Next
End Sub


Sub wordGeneration()
    Dim wordUsed As Array = {"pizza", "noodle", "zombie", "object", "rowin", "running", "elephant", "lion"}
    Dim random As New Random

    randomWord = wordUsed(random.Next(0, 9))
    Label2.Text = randomWord

End Sub
```

Comment: If randomWord.Contains(userInput) Then...

Comment: that worked but now it is repeating "correct" 8 times how do I make it say it just once?

Comment: You probably still have your loop there, you don't need it anymore. letterInput() only needs that single if/else statement inside it

Comment: and how do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant in the comments was that you just need to replace your for loop with a simple if/else. String.Contains checks the whole string already, so there is no need to iterate through each letter anymore:

```
Sub letterInput()
    If randomWord.Contains(userInput) Then
        MessageBox.Show("correct")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("incorrect")
        Label4.Text = counter
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nugs If it worked, then the thing to do is to click the checkmark.  That moves this off the unanswered list and helps other users find good answers